# Check user is login in another system Issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am working with symfony 2

I have checked user is logged in or not from another system as below,
 field in user table:

1. `is_login(tinyint)` 1 at time of login , 0 at time of logout
2. `last_login(datetime)` done entry  at time of login

Table to keep log of all logins - signup_log:

```
id(int -11)
user_id(int-11)
login_time(dat_time)
logout_time(date_time)
```

At time of login I have checked `is_login` from user table if it is '0' then I have allow to login in to system.

There are some problem with above functionality:

1. If user is logged into any system , and system crash
2. If user do not logout properly (just close browser or system)

IN above 2 cases is_login will not set to '0'.

I have no idea for this cases, what to do ?

Comment: If you're using symfony you should check this to handle user, permission, and login check http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html not sure to understand your question though

Comment: try using cookies in browsers and get a track with user id. and we cannot do anything if we are closing because that cookie remains there until it is expires. or you should give that cookie a little time of life..

Comment: if you're using symfony use the [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) for authentication/login/registration and user-handling..

Answer (score 1):

For the point 2 I would use some watchdog strategy. Each user action refreshes a timestamp. In the server side a cron task checks tajar time stamp. If the timestamp is bigger than a threshold consider that the user is logged out. You can get more control on that with a Ajax call that refreshes the timestamp in case that the user can spend long time reading or whatever without sending requests to the server.